# 220v alternatives for Lutron Caseta Smart Lighting?

Tags: electrical, 240v, smart-switch

I need to add another light switch in my home to pair with an existing one. In other words, I have an existing switch that controls a light, and I want to add another one **with no wires** to control the same light (just stick it on a wall and have it communicate wirelessly with a switch in the existing place - either by WiFi or RF).

Turns out there are solutions for this, such as:

[Lutron Caseta](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B07HM6L48C) - which I found out about in this tutorial: [Installing a Wireless Light Switch](https://www.gottabemobile.com/how-to-add-a-second-light-switch-without-wiring/).

[SK-8 Wireless](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B0052ROEB2) - which I found out about in a tutorial on YouTube: [How to Add a Second Light Switch Without Wiring](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ObeJ63E-61E).

[Inovelli Red Series ZWave Dimmer Switch](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B07S1BMMGH) and [C by GE 3-Wire Smart Dimmer Switch](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B082LK16TH) - which are mentioned in this article: [3 Smart Switches That Work With No Neutral Wire](https://thesmartcave.com/smart-switch-with-no-neutral/).

Now the problem is that all of these options are USA versions, and not compatible with my region (Israel, 220v). Does anyone know about alternatives with 220 voltage that ship worldwide?

Answer (score 2):

### Shop in your own hemisphere

The mistake is that your shopping efforts are attuned to North American gear.

The other four continents (Europe, Asia, Africa, Australia) use the same 230V system that you have.  They are actually much larger markets than North America, being choc-a-bloc with first-world countries like Germany and the UK.

Form-factors (box dimensions etc.) can differ among countries, but here, the best guide is **shop domestically**. Either inside your country, or inside your region if your country is not large enough to support a robust electrical industry.

Comment: Yeah but I didn't find... That's why I'm asking

Comment: @AlaaM., try searching for 'European smart light switch' -- Europe's electrical system is basically compatible with yours, and you'll probably find far more results that way than searching for Israel specifically.  You'll still want to check that it's legal to use in your country, but the odds are much much better for European hardware than North American.

Comment: Also, if you happen to know some, you might try searching in a language other than English.  Like Harper says, the 230V market is actually larger than the 120V one, but the 120V market is the largest English-speaking one, so it tends to dominate the English language search results.